# What happens to child processes when I interrupt the execution of the main process?

Tags: c, signals, fork

Imagine I have a process that creates a child process. I also want to change the execution of the signal `SIGINT` to another function once. An outline of the program would be the following:

```
//global variables

void auxiliar_signal() {
    //deallocation of global variables
}

int main () {
    signal(SIGINT, auxiliar_signal);

    int n = fork();

    switch(n) {
        case 0:
            //child process code
        break;

        default:
            //main process code
        break;
    }
}
```

So, what will happen to the child process when I execute `CTRL + C` or I send a `SIGINT` to the main process? Will it stop it's execution? If not, how could I stop the execution of the child process given the case it had an infinite loop in it?

Comment: Nothing will happen to the child process. They run independently after the `fork` (unless explicit IPC code is added). [kill](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) can be used to send a signal to the child including termination signals.

Comment: @kaylum So I could just set `n` as a global variable and execute something like `kill(n, SIGKILL);` in the `auxiliar_signal` function to end the child process then deallocate the memory used by both main process and child?

Comment: Don't need a global variable. `n` is accessible to the parent process as it is now. A typical generalised pattern is to send `SIGINT` first to give the child a chance to exit cleanly. If after some time the child is still running then send the harder `SIGKILL`. Also, please be aware that the parent should call `wait` to "reap" the child process. Otherwise the child process becomes a zombie.

Comment: Also note that only async safe functions should be called in a signal handler. Memory allocation/free functions are not async safe. The general way to handle that is to set a flag in the signal handler that a loop in the non-signal handler code will check.

Comment: @kaylum So, if I understood good, I can't `free` any allocated memory inside `auxiliar_signal` in this case?

Comment: Yes that's right. If the function is not listed in the [signal-safety doc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) then it is best not to call it in a signal handler.

Comment: Note that Ctl-C sends the signal to the entire foreground process group, not just the main process. So unless the child creates a new process group, it will get the interrupt.